# BlackBerry app for different devices

Tags: blackberry, version

Is it necessary to write different versions of Blackberry applications for different devices? For example, I have an application "MyApp", and I need it to run on different devices:

- 9700 - MyApp v1
- 9550 - MyApp v2

Can I write one MyApp for both devices?

Answer (score 2):

That depends on if you want your application to take advantage of specific properties of the devicies or facilities available with the OS version supported on the device. The 9550, for example, is a touch device while the 9700 isn't. There are two broad strategies: 1) write your application to the lowest common denominator (OS and hardware0; 2) write you application to make maximum use of the facilities available on each supported device. So, yes, you can write one MyApp for both devices if that satisfies your goals and users.