# Targeting Multiple Blackberry Devices

Tags: blackberry

I am trying to target a Blackberry application to multiple devices, since there are advanced graphics needed.  I would like to avoid writing multiple versions (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177917/blackberry-app-for-different-devices)).  The target is OS version 5.0, and so far it works as expected on storm2 simulator.

The issue is when I run it on the Bold simulator, the `EditFields` are not accepting input from the keyboard.

I can't seem to find any example how **actually** go about supporting multiple devices.

Thanks,
MD

Comment: possible duplicate of [Blackberry OS version](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5103423/blackberry-os-version)

Comment: @MatthewWillis You're close, except it did not show up in my searches, and it doesn't actually answer my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of good links in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5103423/blackberry-os-version).

In particular, [Marc's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5103423/blackberry-os-version/5111360#5111360) contains links to actual projects which support many OS versions that you can explore and mimic.

Answer (score 1):

Use only the components available to 4.5 and it should work on all different OS versions.

Or make your own custom components.

Comment: I could, but then it won't look very nice.  It will plain text and no interesting graphics.  But if that's what the client wants.